# What is the correct way to use linear regression with original dataset if it was trained on the normalized one?

Tags: python-3.x, numpy, linear-regression

My task was to create a linear regression on the z-score normalized data set, where

[image: X_changed=(X−μ)/σ]

So this is my result
[image: result]

Then I tried to use normalized weights on the original dataset but faced some difficulties:

[image: broken]

So my question is how can this be fixed? My closest attempt was to use such scaling:
[image: my scaling]

[image: Don't know is this valid enough]

Comment: This question isn't suites for StackOverflow, probably it should be on [statistics.se]

Answer (score 1):

After some searching, I've found this discussion:

[Rescaling after feature scaling, linear regression](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21168844/rescaling-after-feature-scaling-linear-regression?rq=1)

[image]
[image]